# Is there a way to use joda time to print the short version of Finnish month names?

Tags: android, jodatime

As the title says: is there a way to do this with joda time on android. For example the month January has its Finnish translation tammikuu and the short version should be tammi.

It does not really matter what format I use (`MMM`or `MMMM`), because the month will be displayed the same: tammikuuta.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: No Joda-Time does not hold its own i18n-resources but just delegates to what it can find in JDK or Android environment based on Java-6-API. And Joda-Time does not know the standalone-mode at all, also not for Finnish (tammikuu = wide standalone, tammi = short standalone). Sorry. By the way, my alternative library Time4A has defined such [asset resources for Finnish](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A/blob/master/time4j-android/src/main/assets/net/time4j/i18n/calendar/iso8601_fi.properties). And ICU4J will surely also have such resources.

Comment: You can also use the Android version of `SimpleDateFormat` which has the [pattern symbol L](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (for standalone month). If your Android resources are up-to-date then this is the built-in way to go (if you can cope with an old-fashioned API).